# awk and regexp from file

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file:

```
first basket with apple
second basket with apricota
third basket with tomato
fourth basket with olives
fifth empty basket
```

I must print each word which contain in end /e,o,y/ letter in each 1,3,5.N string.
Result must be: apple,tomato,empty. 
I can separate 1,3,5 string, but can not separate each word in string and check it

```
awk '{if (NR % 2 != 0); {if (/(y|e|o)$/) print $0}}' inputfile
```

and have in result

```
first basket with apple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$ awk 'NR % 2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i  ~ /[eoy]$/) print $i}' input
apple
tomato
empty
```

**What it does?**

- `NR % 2` selects the lines 1 3 5...
- `if ($i  ~ /[eoy]$/)` checks if each field, wrod ends with a `e` or `o` or `y`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /.*(e|o|y)$/){print $0}}}' file
first basket with apple
third basket with tomato
fifth empty basket
```

To get the words only,

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /.*(e|o|y)$/){print $i}}}' file
apple
tomato
empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `gnu awk` solution (due to multiple characters in `RS`):

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '/([yeo])$/' file
apple
tomato
empty
```

Here `RS` is set to space or newline, so it will run one and one word on each line.